# "Cannot Resolve Symbol" when .setText() used on a child of correct type Android

Tags: java, android, view, parent-child, settext

thanks in advance.

I have multiple TableRow objects in an Android app, each of which contains exactly two EditTexts. I want to have the contents and quantity of editTexts saved and restored when I open/close the app and so I need to have a way to set the text of the EditTexts, but this is where the problem is.

Android Studio is saying "Cannot Resolve Symbol 'setText'":

```
//will loop through each of the TableRows in a tableRowHolder(no problem yet):
for (int i = 0; i < tableRowHolder.getChildCount() && tableRowHolder.getChildAt(i) instanceof android.widget.TableRow; ++i) { 

    //set tableRow to be the i-th child in tableRowHolder (no problem yet)
    TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) tableRowHolder.getChildAt(i);

    //where the problem is("setText" is red), I don't think Java recognises that "tableRow.getChildAt(1)" is an EditText, even though it always will be.
    tableRow.getChildAt(1).setText();

    //this however, is perfectly fine:
    EditText et = new EditText(
    et.setText("");
}
```

To recap, I have:

- A tableRow object always containing exactly two EditTexts

and my problem is that:

- Java seems to not recognise that I am asking for .setText() on a EditText

Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: If you are sure that `tableRow.getChildAt(1)` returns a `EditText`, use a cast: `((EditText) tableRow.getChildAt(1)).setText("");`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like you're casting your `TableRow` out of the `TableRowHolder`, you need to cast the `View` child to an `EditText` before you can call its methods.

```
TableRow tableRow = (TableRow) tableRowHolder.getChildAt(i);

((EditText) tableRow.getChildAt(1)).setText("Some Text");
```

You could optionally wrap your calls inside an *instanceof if-block* to avoid any `ClassCastException`s if there's any chance that the `View` may not be an `EditText` always.

```
View child = tableRow.getChildAt(1);

if (child instanceof EditText) {
    EditText et = (EditText) child;
    et.setText("Some Text");
}
```

Comment: Thanks that's brilliant, I never knew you could cast something like that (:, It won't let me mark it as the answer just yet (4 minutes)